# Toggle all function not working on my todo list

Tags: javascript

My code runs correctly except for the toggle all function; it does nothing at all. There are no error messages

I have proof read several times and attempted using boolean value to replace true and false. Nothing is working. The following is the part that doesnt do anything:
*this. refers to the todo list.
"todos" is an object with two properties: 1. Todo Text, 2. completion status.

The rest of the code already has a for loop in place for displaying todos function as completed or in complete represented by "(x)" for completed and 
"( )" as incomplete next to the name of todo.

```js
toggleAll: function() {
  var totalTodos = this.todos.legth;
  var completedTodos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
    if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
      completedTodos++;
    }
  }
  if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
      this.todos[i].completed = false;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
      this.todos[i].completed = true;
    }
  }
  this.displayTodos();
};
```

It is expected to toggle all as completed if any todos is incomplete, and to toggle all todos as incomplete if all are already completed. Instead, the list remains the same as it was before toggleAll is executed. There are no error messages.

Comment: ... and what is `toggleAll` supposed to do? Mark everything complete? Mark everything incomplete? Swap the complete status of everything, so done->undone and undone->done? — you also have `todos.legth` (where `length` is misspelled) -- you should paste your _actual_ code so you don't get typos. If your actual code says `var totalTodos = this.todos.legth;` then there's a problem right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things, your code is *not* correct since

```
var totalTodos = this.todos.legth
```

won't work. Also you can simplify your code abit.. I will asume totalTodos is an Array. Consider using Array built in functions such as filter, map.

so for instance

```
toggleAll: function() {
    const totalTodos = this.todos.length;
    const todos = this.todos;

    // (1) find out if all are completed using filter
    const areAllCompleted = todos.filter(e => e.completed).length === 
    totalTodos; 

    // (2) Flip all items using Array.map
    this.todos = todos.map(i => {...i, complete: !areAllCompleted })

  this.displayTodos();
};
```

Hopefully the suggested code is easier to read and you are introduced to the following

...

Array.map

Array.filter

! operator

Check out
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I cant believe I did not see the typo. Those seem like very useful alternatives. Ive been doing a online course and we havent gotten there yet. If I learn maps and filters, would they completely replace the method I did it in other situations as well? Im basically trying to see if the codes I'm using are pointless with other easier ways

Comment: If you now how to use Array.map, Array.filter etc they will help you with standard array manipulations, writing your own for, while loops etc is still beneficial, and you should know them. A clear case to use for loops might be performance on cpu see: https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS , but this case is not in alignment to reality (hard to fight for performance at such a level) IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If your code does have the `this.todos.legth` typo in your post, you won't necessarily see an error message because it'll simply return `undefined` instead of throwing some sort of "property not found" exception that you may see in other languages.

```js
this.todos = ["some", "objects", "go", "here"];
console.log(this.todos.legth); // returns undefined
console.log(this.todos.length); // returns 4
```

Then, all your other loops won't do anything because they either iterate to a max value of `undefined` or create conditions such as `completedTodos === totalTodos` -> `0 === undefined`.

Here's the fixed code.

```js
toggleAll: function() {
    var totalTodos = this.todos.legth;
    var completedTodos = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
        if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
            completedTodos++;
        }
    }
    if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
        for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
            this.todos[i].completed = false;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
            this.todos[i].completed = true;
        }

    }
    this.displayTodos();
}
};
```

Comment: I feel so dumb as I read through it so many times. I thought it was the code programmed incorrectly. Thanks!!!